# Save BS4 output in a variable

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am making some sort of football betting program that is going to scrape the fixtures from a website and match them against an Excel file that I have to determine the winner, but that's for another time haha. For now I only have a problem with the scraping.

I have my BS4 output, but I can't store it into a variable in order to use it later. When the print function is inside the for loop, the output is correct, when I take it out, the output is only the last  tag of the page instead of every  tag.

```
    import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url= "https://www.bbc.com/sport/football/scores-fixtures/"
date = input(str("Input the date, hit Enter for today"))
src = url + date

html = requests.get(src).text
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')

select = soup.find_all('abbr')

for abbr in select:
    if abbr.has_attr('title'):
        fixtures = str(abbr['title'])
        print(fixtures)
```

Comment: `fixtures = str(abbr['title'])` reassigns new values to `fixtures` on each iteration. The previous value is lost. You should use a collection, like a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated, throw the fixtures into a list.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url= "https://www.bbc.com/sport/football/scores-fixtures/"
date = input(str("Input the date, hit Enter for today"))
src = url + date

html = requests.get(src).text
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')

select = soup.find_all('abbr')

fixtures_list = []
for abbr in select:
    if abbr.has_attr('title'):
        fixtures = str(abbr['title'])
        print(fixtures)
        fixtures_list.append(fixtures)
```

**Output:**

```
print(fixtures_list)
['Dagenham & Redbridge', 'Salford City', 'Coventry United Ladies', 'Bristol City Women', 'Chapecoense', 'Flamengo']
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot !!